# How to setup the failed connection alerts in log analytics workspace and how to automate it through logic app

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, azure-sql-database

How to setup the failed connection alerts in log analytics workspace and how to automate it through logic app

Tried running with this query in log analytics workspace but it's not working:

SecurityEvent

```
            | where TimeGenerated >= ago(1d)

            | where EventID == 4625
```

but it's not returning any results - but an error instead:

> Where operation failed to resolve table or column  expression with SecurityEvent.

Comment: thanks Marc_s, can you suggest how to get the resullts.

Comment: any suggestions how to enable security events